# Remove curved corners with CSS

Tags: css

I am looking to remove the curved corners from the listings on this site using CSS.

*https://www.marriedin.co.uk/suppliers/*

I've tried various things but cant get it to work.

Would anybody have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What things have you tried?

Comment: Make border-radius:0;

Comment: Put some working code or fiddle with you code

Comment: please, it's not a question. you just submit a task for us.

Comment: Hint: `.type-job_listing.style-grid .job_listing-entry-header`

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Apologies if this was badly worded. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### CSS

```
/* remove radius from container and its border */
    .content-box {
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
/* remove radius from the image itself */
    .job_listing-entry-header.listing-cover.has-image {
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
/* remove radius from the background of the image*/
/*its needed because the images are semi transparent*/
    .job_listing-entry-header.listing-cover.has-image:after {
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css to the bottom of the stylesheet.

```
.listing-cover:after, .type-job_listing.style-grid.job_position_featured .job_listing-entry-header:before, .type-job_listing.style-grid .job_listing-entry-header, .content-box{
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css file:

```
.content-box{border-radius:0 !important;}
.type-job_listing.style-grid .job_listing-entry-header{border-radius:0 !important;}
```

for a future question please explain what you have tried to do

Answer (score -1):

find in  your css

```
.content-box
```

and remove line

```
border-radius : 4px;
```

Also, find 
    .type-job_listing.style-grid .job_listing-entry-header

and remove line

```
border-top-left-radius : 4px;
border-top-right-radius : 4px;
```

It will resolve.